# Maven: webstart, buildnumber and finalName conflict?

Tags: maven, netbeans, buildnumber-maven-plugin, maven-webstart-plugin

I generate a build-number with this part of the POM file:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <buildNumberPropertyName>project.build.number</buildNumberPropertyName>
            <timestampPropertyName>project.build.time</timestampPropertyName>
            <format>{0,date,yyyyMMddHHmmss}</format>
            <items>
                <item>timestamp</item>
            </items>
            <doCheck>false</doCheck>
            <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>create</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

After that i set the finalName to following:

```
    <finalName>
        ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${project.build.number}
    </finalName>
```

I'm also using the webstart-maven-plugin to generate the project as webstart-app.
The webstart-plugin generates a zip-file.
And that all works fine except for one little detail:

On build there is this output:

```
[buildnumber:create]
Storing buildNumber: 20130312133207 at timestamp: 1363091527664
Building jar: D:\projects\myProject\target\myProject-1.0.20130312133207.jar
Building jar: D:\projects\myProject\target\myProject-1.0.20130312133207-sources.jar
Building jar: D:\projects\myProject\target\myProject-1.0.20130312133207-javadoc.jar
Building zip: D:\projects\myProject\target\myProject-1.0.${project.build.number}.zip
```

Why isn't the ${project.build.number} replaced in the zip-file?
Is it because it is zip and not jar?
Why is the version replaced then?
How can i tell the POM to replace the buildNumber in the zip-file?

I already tried using the default $buildNumber instead of the $project.build.number, that also doesn't work.

Edit: I already tried different phases for the two plugins, but no combination worked so far.

Edit2: In case it is interesting for you, how the Webstart-Plugin-part looks like, here is the code:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jnlp</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>

                <!-- JNLP generation -->
                <jnlp>
                    <!-- default values -->
                    <inputTemplateResourcePath>${project.basedir}</inputTemplateResourcePath>
                    <inputTemplate>src/main/jnlp/app.vm</inputTemplate> <!-- relative to inputTemplateResourcePath -->
                    <outputFile>app.jnlp</outputFile> <!-- defaults to launch.jnlp -->

                    <!-- used to automatically identify the jar containing the main class. -->
                    <!-- this is perhaps going to change -->
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.myproject.App</mainClass>
                </jnlp>
                <sign>
                    <keystore>${basedir}/keystore</keystore>
                    <keypass>password</keypass>  <!-- we need to override passwords easily from the command line. ${keypass} -->
                    <storepass>password</storepass> <!-- ${storepass} -->
                    <!--storetype>fillme</storetype-->
                    <alias>MyProjectWebstart</alias>

                    <!--validity>fillme</validity-->

                    <!-- only required for generating the keystore -->
                    <dnameCn>MyProjectWebstart</dnameCn>
                    <dnameOu>MyName</dnameOu>
                    <dnameO>MyCompany</dnameO>
                    <dnameL>MyTown</dnameL>
                    <dnameSt>MyState</dnameSt>
                    <dnameC>MyCountry</dnameC>

                    <verify>true</verify> <!-- verify that the signing operation succeeded -->

                    <!-- KEYSTORE MANAGEMENT -->
                    <keystoreConfig>
                        <delete>true</delete> <!-- delete the keystore -->
                        <gen>true</gen>       <!-- optional shortcut to generate the store. -->
                    </keystoreConfig>
                </sign>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I used the code in the example there: [Looking for Webstart Maven Plugin sample application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195545/looking-for-webstart-maven-plugin-sample-application)

Comment: no one can help? not even a question about what i did or something?

Comment: First i would suggest to use the defaults for the property names like buildNumber, timestamp instead project.build (they might interfere with project.build etc.). Furthermore i would like to know why you need to change the name in that way, cause the finalName works only for the file in the outputDirectory folder and not for artifacts which will be deployed. Apart from that I woud like to know how your assembly descriptor looks like?

Answer (score 0):

do not set your buildNumberPropertyName parameter to project.build.ANYTHING.. expression starting with ${project.XXX} resolves based on the MavenProject object so you say in ${project.build.date} that there is a getter getBuild() that returns an object that has getter  getDate() which is not correct.

just name the buildNumberPropertyName and timestampPropertyName parameters differently, eg. myBuildNumber and myTimestamp and change the rest of the pom accordingly